# On Error works in first and doesn't work in second instance. Bug?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a very strange problem here. Here's the code:

```
reqLang = "ENG"
    Select Case reqLang
        Case "CRO", "ENG"
            'first loop -------------------------------------
            On Error GoTo reqLangVisible
            i = 1
            'Loop until ccCROENG's are all hidden and then go to reqLangVisible.
            Do
                ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ccCROENG")(i) _
                    .Range.Font.Hidden = True 'hides all CCs
                i = i + 1
            Loop
reqLangVisible:
            'second loop -------------------------------------
            On Error GoTo langOut
            i = 1
            'Loop until ccreqLang's are all visible and then go to langOut.
            Do
                ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("cc" & reqLang)(i) _
                    .Range.Font.Hidden = False 'activates reqLang CCs
                i = i + 1
            Loop ' CAN'T GET OUT -----------------------------------
        Case "CROENG"
            i = 1
            'Loop until ccCROENG's are all visible and then go to langOut.
            Do
                On Error GoTo langOut
                    ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ccCROENG")(i) _
                        .Range.Font.Hidden = False 'Shows all CCs
                i = i + 1
            Loop
    End Select
langOut:
MsgBox "Success!" '------- yeah, not really.
Stop
```

I hope it's clear enough what it's trying to do (at least programming-wise). I have multiple `ContentControls(CCs)` with same titles and tags. The problem I end up with is marked with *CAN'T GET OUT*, because, you guessed it - I can't get of this second loop! I end up with the `Out of range error` because it runs out of `CCs`.

What's even weirder is that it actually did get out of the first loop which has the exact same On Error statement, thought pointing to a different section.
Is it me, or did I just - however unlikely - run onto a bug in VBA?
In any case, is there a solution or at least a workaround?

Comment: You need something to exit you out of that loop. Change it to a do while loop with an exit instruction.

Comment: Quoted from this [Error handling link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm) `When the first error is raised, execution transfers to the line following  reqLangVisible:. The error hander is still active when the second error occurs, and therefore the second error is not trapped by the On Error statement.` Furthermore from the same link: `You can't use  to the On Error Goto <label>:  statement merely skip over lines`.

Comment: Are you using error handling to avoid having to get the count of the collection returned by `SelectContentControlsByXXX` or using a For Each loop?

Comment: @TimWilliams: not sure what you mean. I have a limited number of CCs, (say, 82) and I want the code to loop until it hits 83. Once it hits 83, it triggers an error, which then I use as an indicator that it's time to end the loop.

Comment: What I'm saying is typically you only use error handling for dealing with *unexpected or unpredictable* situations, such as not being able to access a drive, or finding you have no network access.  Error handling is not intended as a substitute for reasonable checks which could otherwise be done.  i.e. collections have a `Count` property which you can use when looping over their items, so avoiding any error caused by trying to access `Item(n+1)` when there are only `n` items (and you *know* `n` from `Count`).  Alternatively, use a `For Each` loop.

Comment: @TimWilliams, could you please show how this particular issue would be solved with a `For Each` loop? That seems to be the only way to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you only use error handling for dealing with *unexpected or unpredictable situations*, such as not being able to access a drive, or finding you have no network access.

Error handling is not intended as a substitute for reasonable checks which could otherwise be done. i.e. collections have a Count property which you can use when looping over their items, so avoiding any error caused by trying to access Item(n+1) when there are only n items (and here you *know* n from `Count`). Alternatively, use a For Each loop.

Here's some sample code demonstrating use of two methods for looping over your controls:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim cc1 As ContentControls, cc2 As ContentControls
    Dim c, i As Long

    With ActiveDocument
        Set cc1 = .SelectContentControlsByTag("tbTag")
        Set cc2 = .SelectContentControlsByTitle("tbTitle")
    End With

    Debug.Print "cc1 has " & cc1.Count
    Debug.Print "cc2 has " & cc2.Count

    'use the Count property
    For i = 1 To cc1.Count
        Set c = cc1(i)
        c.Range.Font.Hidden = True
    Next i

    'use a For Each loop
    For Each c In cc2
        c.Range.Font.Hidden = False
    Next c

End Sub
```

This is the type of scenario for which this type of flow control is designed.

Applied to your original code:

```
Sub Tester2()
    Dim reqLang, cc As ContentControls, c

    reqLang = "ENG"

    Select Case reqLang

        Case "CRO", "ENG"

            Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ccCROENG")
            SetTextHidden cc, True

            Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("cc" & reqLang)
            SetTextHidden cc, False

        Case "CROENG"

            Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ccCROENG")
            SetTextHidden cc, False

    End Select

    MsgBox "Success!" '-- yeah really

End Sub

Sub SetTextHidden(cc As ContentControls, MakeHidden As Boolean)
    Dim c
    For Each c In cc
        c.Range.Font.Hidden = MakeHidden
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you've read my comment, and to formally answer your question, it is not a bug. 
You just need to use `Error Handling Routines` correctly. 
What you're trying to do is somewhat like below. HTH.

```
Select Case reqlang

Case "CRO", "ENG"
    On Error Resume Next '~~> ignores the error when encountered
    '~~> Your loop which possibly creates the error goes here
    On Error Goto 0 '~~> resets the actively triggered error handling

Case "CROENG"
    On Error Resume Next '~~> ignores the error when encountered
    '~~> Your loop which possibly creates the error goes here
    On Error Goto 0 '~~> resets the actively triggered error handling

End Select

MsgBox "Success"
```

But as the link suggest, you need to handle errors and not simply disregard them.
 Try cheking on the actual error and find a way to correct it or avoid it.
You'll be surprise that you won't even be needing the `Error Handling Routine`.

Comment: Tried it, but it only creates an endless loop. It ends up stuck in the first one. Maybe it's because the next line of code is `i = i + 1` instead of `On Error Goto 0`?